# SQL barks at SELECT TOP (1) for too many return values

Tags: sql-server

I simplified the code as

```
SELECT TOP(1) e.name
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
ORDER BY dbo.editDist(e.name, 'Robert Johnson') ASC
```

where `EMPLOYEE` is a table containing names and other info, and `editDist` is a user created function that takes two strings as input and return one int value.

SQL complains:

> 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.'

As far as I see `TOP(1)` should definitely return one row, and this line causes error. What might be the problem?

Comment: Then the problem should be your function `dbo.editDist`

Comment: More rows are returned from this table function: `dbo.editDist(e.name, 'Robert Johnson')`.

Comment: show  `dbo.editDist(e.name,'Robert Johnson')` code.

Comment: Do you still get an error if you replace `ORDER BY` clause with: `ORDER BY (SELECT TOP 1 funcField FROM dbo.editDist(e.name, 'Robert Johnson')) ASC` ?

Comment: This looks like SQL Server.   Does MySQL have anything to do with this?

Comment: Thanks guys!! I figured out one SELECT statement inside the editDist function return more than 1 val.